# Working with a reactive() dataframe inside eventReactive()?

Tags: r, shiny

I was hoping someone could provide some guidance on resolving an issue I have. For background, I'm trying to create an interface for users to upload a csv of news stories, which they can then annotate as relevant or not relevant for the purposes of a classifier. What should appear once the user has uploaded a csv is a table output with selectable rows. The text associated with the selected row would then display in the lower right.

The setup I have attempted is to put the user-uploaded spreadsheet into a reactive(), which is then worked with as part of an eventReactive() to annotate sentences as relevant or not. However, the table does not appear when I run the app, and there are no error or warning messages. I've tried modifying my approach to use reactiveValues() and observe() when loading the csv, but I encounter the same issue. I've included the code below, as well as a toy dataset.

I've spent the past couple of hours scouring the web for solutions, but haven't had much luck. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Data

```
sample <- data.frame(relevant = c('','','','',''), lede=c('first lede', 'second lede', 'third lede', 'fourth lede', 'fifth lede'))
write.csv(sample, 'sample.csv', row.names=F)
```

Code for app

```
library(shiny) 
library(DT)


#######################################################
### INTERFACE
#######################################################

in1 <-   radioButtons("truefalse", "Change values in 'keep' column here", 
                      choices=c("TRUE", "FALSE"),
                      selected = "TRUE", inline = FALSE)
in2 <-   actionButton("goButton", "Update Table")
in3 <-   downloadButton("download_data", label = "Download")
in4 <- fileInput('datafile', 'Choose CSV file',
                 accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain'))

out1 <- textOutput("text")
out2 <- dataTableOutput("sheet", width = "30%")

in5 <- textInput("save_file", "New file name:", value="updated_data.csv")
in6 <- actionButton("save", "Save updated data")

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Text Annotater"),
                column(6, out2),
                column(6, in4, in1, in2, in5, in6, out1))


#######################################################
### SERVER 
#######################################################
server <- function(input, output){

  sheet <- reactive({
    infile <- input$datafile
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(NULL)
    }
    tbl = read.csv(infile$datapath, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    return(tbl)
  })



  # reactive dataframe object
  df <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    if(selected_row_id()>0 &&input$goButton>0){  
      sheet()[selected_row_id(),1] <<- input$truefalse
    }
    sheet()
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  # selectable data table 
  output$sheet <- renderDataTable({
    df()
  }, selection = "single")

  # selected row ID from data table
  selected_row_id <- reactive({
    input$sheet_rows_selected
  })

  # text of article
  output$text<-renderText({sheet()[input$sheet_rows_selected, "lede"]})

  # Save when click the button
  observeEvent(input$save, {
    write.csv(df, input$save_file, row.names = FALSE)
  })

  # download button
  output$download_data <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "updated_data.csv",
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(df(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I think you should put all the `reactive`s outside of `eventReactive`, because you can always check if the `input$goButton` (in your case) is triggered inside `reactive` function. Also you do not render anything for outputs inside `eventReactive`, use `ObserveEvent` for the rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should made several changes to make your `reactive` and the output works.

- remove the `return` in the expression of `reactive` because `reactive` only captures the last output from the expression.
- Move all the `reactive` outside of any function because you can always check if the `input$goButton` (in your case) is triggered inside reactive function.
- Use `ObserveEvent` for the triggering of events (like `input$goButton`) instead of `eventReactive` because `eventReactive` only gives out a value (rather than renders for outputs and keeps them in the scope).
- Use `reactiveValues` for any variable (df_sheet) that changes values in `ObserveEvent`
- Change `df` to `df_sheet`

Here is the modified `server` function:

```
server <- function(input, output){
  v <- reactiveValues(df_sheet = NULL)

  sheet <- reactive({
    infile <- input$datafile
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      NULL
    } else {
      tbl = read.csv(infile$datapath, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

      if(!is.null(selected_row_id())) {
        if (selected_row_id() > 0){  
          tbl[selected_row_id(),1] <- input$truefalse
        }
      } 

      tbl
    }
  })


  # selected row ID from data table
  selected_row_id <- reactive({
    input$sheet_rows_selected
  })


  # reactive dataframe object
  observeEvent(input$goButton, {

    v$df_sheet <- sheet()

    # selectable data table 
    output$sheet <- renderDataTable({
      v$df_sheet
    }, selection = "single")

  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)


  # Save when click the button
  observeEvent(input$save, {

    # text of article
    output$text<-renderText({v$df_sheet[input$sheet_rows_selected, "lede"]})

    # download button
    output$download_data <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "updated_data.csv",
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(v$df_sheet, file, row.names = FALSE)
      }
    )

    write.csv(v$df_sheet, input$save_file, row.names = FALSE)
  })

}
```

Comment: Hi @raymkchow. Thanks for the response. The answer you posted does fix the issue of the data table not rendering. However, it introduces a new issue where changes to the "relevant" column are not tracked. So, each time the "update" button is clicked, the sheet is not actually updated. It's just being read in again, and a TRUE/FALSE label applied to the selected column. My thinking is that the if/else statement for updating the column should be outside of that first reactive statement. Another issue is that the table does not appear when the file is read in, but only after clicking update.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by storing the data in a `reactiveValues`, replacing `eventReactive()` with `observeEvent`, then updating the data using `isolate()`.

Working server code

```
server <- function(input, output){
  v = reactiveValues(df_sheet = NULL)
  sheet <- reactive({
    infile <- input$datafile
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(NULL)
    }
    tbl = read.csv(infile$datapath, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    v$df_sheet = tbl
    tbl
  })



  # reactive dataframe object
   observeEvent(input$goButton, {
     isolate({
       if(!is.null(selected_row_id())) {
         if (selected_row_id() > 0){  
           v$df_sheet[selected_row_id(),1] <- input$truefalse
         }
       } 
    })
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  # selectable data table 
  output$sheet <- renderDataTable({
    v$df_sheet[,c(1,2)]
  }, selection = "single")

  # selected row ID from data table
  selected_row_id <- reactive({
    input$sheet_rows_selected
  })

  # text of article
  output$text<-renderText({sheet()[input$sheet_rows_selected, "lede"]})

  # Save when click the button
  observeEvent(input$save, {
    write.csv(v$df_sheet, paste('data/',input$save_file, sep=''), row.names = FALSE)
  })

  # download button
  output$download_data <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "updated_data.csv",
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(v$df_sheet, paste('data/', file, sep=''), row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```