# User-interactive table made from reactive data

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am very new to Shiny and struggle to understand reactivity.

Context : I want user to choose a name for a column, add this column to a reactive table and then edit this table. The table is reactive (it comes from an uploaded file filtered by user).

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49656365/10264278) answer everything work fine with a non-reactive table (see `mydata <- mtcars[1:5,]`).
But it doesn't work when `mydata` becomes reactive!

**Here is a reproductible working example with NON-REACTIVE data from [@dww](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49656365/10264278) answer:**

```
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h2("The mtcars data"),
  rHandsontableOutput("mytable"),
  textInput('NewCol', 'Enter new column name'),
  radioButtons("type", "Column type:",
    c("Integer" = "integer",
      "Floating point" = "numeric",
      "Text" = "character")),
  actionButton("goButton", "Update Table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  mydata <- mtcars[1:5,]
  output$mytable = renderRHandsontable(df())
  df <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    if(input$NewCol!="" && !is.null(input$NewCol) && input$goButton>0){
      if (input$type == "integer") v1 <- integer(NROW(mydata))
      if (input$type == "numeric") v1 <- numeric(NROW(mydata))
      if (input$type == "character") v1 <- character(NROW(mydata))
      newcol <- data.frame(v1)
      names(newcol) <- input$NewCol
      mydata <<- cbind(mydata, newcol)
    }
    rhandsontable(mydata, stretchH = "all")
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  observe(if (!is.null(input$mytable)) mydata <<- hot_to_r(input$mytable))
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I have unsuccessfully tried these changes inside the code (basically I have changed all `mydata` for `mydata()`):

```
server <- function(input, output) {

# mydata <- reactive({ }) #make mydata a reactive object

output$mytable = renderRHandsontable(df())
df <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    if(input$NewCol!="" && !is.null(input$NewCol) && input$goButton>0){
        if (input$type == "integer") v1 <- integer(NROW(mydata()))
        if (input$type == "numeric") v1 <- numeric(NROW(mydata()))
        if (input$type == "character") v1 <- character(NROW(mydata()))
        newcol <- data.frame(v1)
        names(newcol) <- input$NewCol
        mydata <<- cbind(mydata(), newcol)
    }
    rhandsontable(mydata(), stretchH = "all")
}, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
observe(if (!is.null(input$mytable)) mydata() <<- hot_to_r(input$mytable))}
```

I did not find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808023/working-with-a-reactive-dataframe-inside-eventreactive) question answers/comments useful to answer my problem).

**Could you explain how to use a reactive `mydata` inside @dww awesome answer?**

[EDIT : title updated to better fit the answer]

Answer (score 1):

I trimmed some extra features, like column data types... As a general rule - anything which you'd be rendering, can become reactive just by wrapping it in "reactive". Below I use "reactiveValues" but other reactive methods would work too.

A generalised way of making your output reactive to changes in the data's input -

```
foo_func = function() return(mydata)
foo_func_reactive = reactive(foo_func)
output$foo = renderMethod( foo_func_reactive() )
```

For your example:

```
shinyApp(

ui = fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("out_tbl"),
  textInput(inputId = "in_txt", label = "New column name"),
  actionButton(inputId = "in_btn1", label = "Add new column to the table above ..."),
  actionButton(inputId = "in_btn2", label = "... Or, generate new data")
),


server = function(input, output, session) {

  # establishes tbl_react as the holder for our reactive data, and pre-fills it for the first display with 1,2,3
  tbl_react <- reactiveValues(tbl = 
    data.frame(a = c(1,2,3))
  )

   # button one adds a new column with the inputted name
  observeEvent(input$in_btn1,{
    newcolname <- as.character(input$in_txt)
    newcol <- character(NROW(tbl_react$tbl))
    tbl_react$tbl <- cbind(tbl_react$tbl, newcol)
    colnames(tbl_react$tbl) <- c(colnames(tbl_react$tbl)[1:ncol(tbl_react$tbl)-1], newcolname)
  })

  # to show our output data is reactive, we can take a dependancy on button two to generate new data - this could instead be using an uploaded file
  observeEvent(input$in_btn2,{
    tbl_react$tbl <- data.frame(b = c(9,10,11))
  })


  output$out_tbl = renderRHandsontable( rhandsontable(tbl_react$tbl) )


  }
)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, your in-code comments were very helpful to solve my problem!

Comment: one problem though, when you add a column, edit it and then add again a column, it erase the values previously files. How do you avoid this?

Comment: EDIT : the code of the reproductible ex in my question does not erase filled values when columns are added